# How to print the attribute value from xml using xmlstarlet?

Tags: shell, xmlstarlet

I have an xml in below format, how to just list root/target/parts/name alone?

With below xml, I need to print

```
wheel
door
```

```
<root>
  <target type="CAR">
    <parts name="wheel" year="2020">
      <model type="string">202005</model>
      <city>SanDiego</city>
    </parts>
  </target>
  <target type="VAN">
    <parts name="door" year="2019">
      <model type="string">201906</model>
      <city>la</city>
    </parts>
  </target>
</root>
```

I couldn't find the right options, I tried below (and many other) but it prints the whole parts

```
 xmlstarlet sel -t -c "/root/target/parts"  -v "@name" foo.xml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want:

```
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/root/target/parts/@name' foo.xml
wheel
door
```

Comment: I need to get `year` when `parts/name=wheel`, tried `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/root/target[parts/@name=wheel]/@year' foo.xml` and many other, but unsuccessful, any help please? basically need to get `2020` when `root/target/parts name=wheel`

Comment: `xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/root/target/parts[@name = "wheel"]/@year' data.xml` seems to work for me.

Comment: Thank you so much, also, xmlstarlet returns `1` if there is no `year`, say if I have `<parts name="wheel">`, can I make it to not throw error (meaning, return 0) ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Probably easier just to write your code to deal with that situation.